# Spurious C++ destructor call under Visual Studio 2008 (absent under GCC)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

Take the following (contrived) class hierarchy that prints to the console from the constructors and destructors:

```
#include <iostream>

class A { 
public:
  A() { std::cout << "A"; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "~A"; } 
};

class B : public A { 
public:   
  B() { std::cout << "B"; }
  ~B() { std::cout << "~B"; } 
};

void func(A a) { }

int main() {   
  B b;
  func(b);
  std::cout << "X";
  return 0; 
}
```

Compiled under linux with gcc, it prints `AB~AX~B~A` as expected (the `~A` printed before `X` is a result of the pass-by-value to `func` which creates a copy that is destructed when the function returns).

But compiled under windows with VS2008 it prints `AB~A~AX~B~A` - where does the extra `~A` come from? It vanishes if the copy xtor is explicitly defined `A(A& that) {};` or if the destructor is declared virtual (as it should be, arguably).

Comment: Methinks Linux vs Windows is a total red herring. The real issue will be GCC vs Visual Studio. And given that you're using a really old version of VS, I won't be surprised if it's a bug. However, what version of GCC are you using? You didn't specify that, and maybe it's even older.

Comment: Anyhow my guess is the two `~A` generated by the (unspecified) `func` must be (1) the in-function local copy of `b` being dtord and (2) the _passed_ rvalue temporary copy of `b` being dtord. The important question would be whether this still happens in newer versions of VS, not a 7-year-old one!

Comment: I doubt if the second Output (in VS) is correct? Conceptually shouldn't be, as far as i know. Ok, just to point out one more thing in your statement, why would copy constructor vanishes ~A, it shhouldn't? Correct me if i am wrong, it 's as a result of destructor call not constructor call.

Comment: Out of curiosity... if you change `func(A a)` to `func(B b)`, do you get consistent results between GCC and VS?  Just wondering if the slicing is the cause of the difference in behavior.

Comment: @Equality7-2521i doubt slicing would show such behavior, also in mentioned classes slicing won't come in picture as both classes are identical in structure.

Comment: Can you show what MSVC does when the copy constructor of `A` prints something? My guess is that there somehow is an extra temporary in MSVC used to implement the slicing.

Comment: I'm interested in whether slicing explains the misimplementation, but I'm a lot more interested in whether a decently modern version of VS fixes it. I don't have a copy... yet?

Comment: By the way MSVC2013 agrees with MSVC2008

Comment: By running the code with the debugger the impression I get is that the observation of @BaummitAugen is right.

Comment: Looking forward to a test of the question posed by Baum mit Augen (unless that's exactly what marom did! I can't be sure). Also curious whether the brand new VS2015 exhibits this too.

Comment: @instance not sure what you are talking about, this code is definitely slicing (an `A` is created by value from a `B`)

Comment: @underscore_d If you wait for me to test this, you'll wait in vain. I do not own any Microsoft compilers.

Comment: Do you get the same extra destructor from the code `{ A a = b; }` and `{ A a(b); }`  ?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I meant just anyone, not specifically you. I too am unlikely to acquire VS any time soon.

Comment: Running the code [here](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) I don't get the effect you see.  Looks like this is fixed in version 19 of the compiler, which I think is MSVC2015.  As a later version of the product seems to have fixed the bug, I'm not sure what good a bug report would do you.

Comment: @Yakk Funny... I was just going to comment that I ran the code there and I did get the effect described by the OP.

Comment: @bogdan interesting.  My slight variation didn't cause it to happen.  I added `A(A const&){ std::cout << "copyA"; }` and the effect goes away.  Puzzling.

Comment: @Yakk Yes, that was mentioned by the OP: a user-provided copy constructor makes the problem go away. I also verified that explicitly defaulting the copy constructor still causes the issue. So, it looks like the defaulted constructor triggers the effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments suggest that MSVC 2008 uses a temporary that g++ doesn't, to pass the parameter. If so, this is a bug. From C++03 [dcl.init]/12:

> The initialization that occurs in argument passing, function return, throwing an exception (15.1), handling an exception (15.3), and brace-enclosed initializer lists (8.5.1) is called *copy-initialization* and is equivalent to the form
>   `T x = a;`

Now here is the crucial bit.  In `T x = a;`, if `a` is *not* a `T` or derived from `T`, then that is equivalent to `T x = T(a);`, and an extra temporary is conceptually used. (This temporary is eligible for copy-elision).

However, if `a` is a `T` or derived from `T`, then there must not be an extra temporary.It is the same as `T x(a);`.

In this question's code, since `B` derives from `A`, there must not be a temporary.

The supporting text in C++03 is under [dcl.init]/14 (I have highlighted the parts relevant to this question's code sample):

> If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> - If the class is an aggregate (8.5.1), and the initializer is a brace-enclosed list, see 8.5.1.
> - If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, **or a derived class of**, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). **The constructor so selected is called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression(s) as its argument(s)**. If no constructor applies, or the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed.
> - **Otherwise** (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3). If the conversion cannot be done or is ambiguous, the initialization is ill-formed. The function selected is called with the initializer expression as its argument; if the function is a constructor, **the call initializes a temporary** of the destination type. The result of the call (which is the temporary for the constructor case) is then used to direct-initialize, according to the rules above, the object that is the destination of the copy-initialization. In certain cases, an imple-
>     mentation is permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this direct-initialization by constructing the intermediate result directly into the object being initialized; see 12.2, 12.8.

Comment: For ref, what would be the best way for VS users to report this to MS? The only guide I found on a quick search requires installing the Feedback extension: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=26698 Things only start to get interesting around #8.

Comment: No extension required; just go to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/) and click "Submit a Bug."  Thanks for reporting the issue!

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Looks like this was reported before: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/757354/c-destructor-is-called-twice-on-temporary-created-object. Unfortunately, the issue is marked as `Deferred`. Any idea if there are any plans for fixing this? It could cause some subtle portability issues.